# ¿Cómo añado un salto de línea antes de un patrón?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, procesamiento-de-texto, salto-de-linea

Tengo un texto muy extenso generado por la unión de muchos textos.
Necesito un formato en concreto *(formato MALLET).

Por lo que tendría que quedarme algo con la siguiente estructura:

```
texto0 X Exitus es un término latino significa «salida» y se emplea en ... 
texto1 X Levon Aronian (nacido el 6 de octubre de 1982). Es un gran ...
texto2 X La pérdida es la carencia o privación de lo que se poseía. Artículos ...

    .
    .
    .
```

Es decir, que cada artículo, fuese una línea.

El problema es que lo que tengo difiere de lo que necesito, es decir, yo tengo algo así:

```
texto0 X Exitus es un término latino significa «salida» y se emplea en ... texto1 X Levon Aronian (nacido el 6 de octubre de 1982). Es un gran ... texto2 X La pérdida es la carencia o privación de lo que se poseía. Artículos ...
```

Y por esto quiero añadir, a ser posible utilizando la terminal de Linux, un salto de línea, antes de cada **textoX**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres añadir un salto de línea antes de cada ocurrencia de "texto", puedes usar sed:

```
sed $'s/texto/\\\ntexto/g' fichero
```

Lo que hace es usar el patrón `s/busca/reemplaza/g`, donde `g` quiere decir "hazlo tantas veces como puedas". Usamos `$'`...`\\\n` porque el salto de línea necesita ser escapado para poder usarse correctamente.

Comment: El único añadido sería que estos cambios se guardasen.

Comment: @IdoiaPico tienes dos opciones: 1. Redirigir a otro archivo con `sed '...' fichero > nuevo_fichero`, 2. Hacer que el cambio se haga en el fichero que ya tienes: `sed -i.bak '...' fichero`, que guardará una copia del original como `fichero.bak` y modificará `fichero`.

Comment: Hay un nuevo problemilla, entiendo que de fácil solución. Había textos que si tenía ese salto de línea, por lo que ahora, a cuenta gotas, pero hay saltos de línea completos, es decir, sobraría un salto de línea. Pero si borro todos los saltos de línea, volveré a estar como al principio.

Comment: @IdoiaPico necesitaría más datos, si hay un patrón sí puede hacerse; si no, no.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve tanteando un poco y llegue a que la forma más sencilla es la sgte. sintaxis:

`sed 's/patrón/\ntextoadicional/g' fichero`

En donde `'s` comienza la acción de *substitute o supersede* (reemplazar en español); `/patrón` es el texto a buscar; `/\n...` crea un salto de línea justo donde encuentra la palabra `patrón`; `...textoadicional` es por si deseas agregar texto adicional luego del salto de linea, pero sino entonces la sintaxis sería:

```
sed 's/patrón/\n/g' fichero
```

y finalmente `/g'` se refiere a *global*, que indica que haga la operación **no en el primer** `texto` **que encuentre** sino **en todo el fichero**.

Espero ayude ;)